# R: for a new variable in row [i] compare row-comprehensive in column x and y

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am looking for a code like a for-loop, which looks at all rows of certain columns to create a new variable for row [i].

I have a data frame which includes basically three columns. Interval start, interval end and measuring date. In all three columns the values have the format YearMonthDayHourMinute. The measuring date is continuous all 10 minutes. The interval are just short periods, that leave a lot of NAs where the measuring date is not met.

The data frame looks like this:

```
interval_start interval_end measuring_date
1             NA           NA   201805021210
2   201805021220 201805021250   201805021220
3             NA           NA   201805021230
4             NA           NA   201805021240
5             NA           NA   201805021250
6             NA           NA   201805021300
```

Now, I want to R to create a new column, that gives a "Yes" where the measuring period lies within the interval, and a "No" where it doesn't.

Like this:

```
interval_start interval_end measuring_date within_interval
1             NA           NA   201805021210              No
2   201805021220 201805021250   201805021220             Yes
3             NA           NA   201805021230             Yes
4             NA           NA   201805021240             Yes
5             NA           NA   201805021250             Yes
6             NA           NA   201805021300              No
```

So I want R to take the measuring_date of row 1 and compare it to the interval_start and interval_end of row 1,2,3,4,5 and 6. Same for measuring_date of row 2 and so on.
The Problem I have now is that I've tried for-loops with if else and nested for-loops (see below) but R seems not to be able to take the measuring_date of row 1 and compare it with all rows of interval_start and interval_end. It compares only within the same row. So all I can get is:

```
interval_start interval_end measuring_date within_interval
1             NA           NA   201805021210              No
2   201805021220 201805021250   201805021220             Yes
3             NA           NA   201805021230              No
4             NA           NA   201805021240              No
5             NA           NA   201805021250              No
6             NA           NA   201805021300              No
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? Maybe there are solutions outside of a for-loop, that I didn't come across. 
I've been searching the whole internet but didn't find any solution which left me  quite frustrated. Even my supervisor is helpless.. 
I hope my question is clear enough, sorry, I am using stackoverflow for the first time..

```
for (i in 1:nrow(masterX)){ 

  masterX$Within_Searching_Period[i] <- NA 

  for (j in 1:nrow(masterX)){

    if (masterX$MESS_DATUM[i] >= masterX$time_date_start_min[j] & 
        masterX$MESS_DATUM[i] <= masterX$time_date_end_min[j]) {

      masterX$Within_Searching_Period[i] <- "YES"

    } else {masterX$Within_Searching_Period[i] <- "NO"

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of focusing on the loop, it's better practice to try to write vectorized code. I've used some `lubridate` and `tidyverse` syntax. If you deal with dates a lot, it's worth looking at `lubridate`'s documentation.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
data %>%
mutate_at(vars(time_date_start_min, time_date_end_min, MESS_DATUM), ymd_hm) %>%
mutate(within_interval = 
           ifelse(MESS_DATUM %within% interval(time_date_start_min, time_date_end_min) %in% TRUE, "Yes", "No"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Since I have other variables in my data frame, I cannot use `mutate_all`, but instead used `mutate(interval_start = ymd_hm, interval_end = ymd_hm, Date = ymd_hm)`. R gives me an error, saying "Column `interval_start` is of unsupported type function". How can I get rid of this?

Comment: To use that syntax, you'll have to do `mutate(interval_start = ymd_hm(interval_start), interval_end = ymd_hm(interval_end), Date = ymd_hm(Date))`. When you `mutate_all`, it calls the function `ymd_hm` on all columns. But when you just call `mutate`, you have to specify not just how, but also what you're mutating.

Comment: So, this now seems to work, but gives some warnings `Warning messages:
1:  45 failed to parse. 
2:  45 failed to parse. 
3: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. `
now, it gives me the table in the console (I'm using R studio) but when I call up my dataframe, there is no column called "within_interval"

Comment: `Failed to parse` means that this solution failed to transform the contents of the variable into a date format. Could you `dput(head(df, 20))` where `df` is the name of your table and post the results here?

Comment: Unfortunately the data frame is so big, that it would go beyond the scope to post this here

Comment: This would only print the first 20 rows and would provide a reproducible example so we can troubleshoot code in the actual data. If there are too many columns, you can filter only the relevant columns as well.

Comment: `> dput(head(masterX2[, c(32,33,54)], 20))
structure(list(time_date_start_min = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "201805021220", 
"NA", "201805021220", "NA", "NA", "NA", "201805021220", "201805021220", 
"NA", "201805021220", "NA", "201805021220", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA"), time_date_end_min = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "201805021520", 
"NA", "201805021520", "NA", "NA", "NA", "201805021520", "201805021520", 
"NA", "201805021520", "NA", "201805021520", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA"), `

Comment: `MESS_DATUM = c(201805021220, 201805021230, 201805021240, 
201805021250, 201805021300, 201805021310, 201805021320, 201805021330, 
201805021340, 201805021350, 201805021400, 201805021410, 201805021420, 
201805021430, 201805021440, 201805021450, 201805021500, 201805021510, 
201805021520, 201805021530)), row.names = c("218", "219", "22032", 
"1", "2221", "2", "22410", "22510", "22610", "3", "4", "22910", 
"5", "23110", "6", "233", "23410", "23510", "23610", "237"), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Sorry, head to put it in 2 comments, it was still too long even though I left out all variables that I don't need for that. "time_date_start_min" and "time_date_end_min" is my interval, "MESS_DATUM" is the measuring date. sorry, it's half german, half english ;)

Comment: I've edited the answer so it works in this format. Indeed, it gives 'failed to parse' errors, but this is due to the 'NA's and can be safely ignored. It should work in a data frame with more columns since they're not being touched by the `mutate_at` function.

Comment: still, if i call up the data frame, there is no column called "within_interval" that has a "NO" or "YES". this column only seems to appeas in the console, but when I click on my dataframe to look at it, there is no "within_interval" column.

Comment: You have to save it into a variable. Just add `data <-` before `data %>%`

Comment: thanks for the help, but it still gives me the data frame with a Yes only in the rows where the interval directly fits.. like the third data frame that I posted in my original question. Which is not what I am looking for. 
It seems there is no solution. R cannot read cross-rows for that..

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` package, you can use non-equi join to find if measuring_date is within any interval:

```
DT[, within_interval := 
    DT[DT, .N > 0 ,on=.(interval_start <= measuring_date, interval_end >= measuring_date), by=.EACHI]$V1
]
```

output:

```
        interval_start        interval_end      measuring_date within_interval
1:                <NA>                <NA> 2018-05-02 12:10:00           FALSE
2: 2018-05-02 12:20:00 2018-05-02 12:50:00 2018-05-02 12:20:00            TRUE
3:                <NA>                <NA> 2018-05-02 12:30:00            TRUE
4:                <NA>                <NA> 2018-05-02 12:40:00            TRUE
5:                <NA>                <NA> 2018-05-02 12:50:00            TRUE
6:                <NA>                <NA> 2018-05-02 13:00:00           FALSE
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("interval_start,interval_end,measuring_date
NA,NA,201805021210
201805021220,201805021250,201805021220
NA,NA,201805021230
NA,NA,201805021240
NA,NA,201805021250
NA,NA,201805021300", colClasses="character")
DT[, (names(DT)) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct, format="%Y%m%d%H%M")]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I use     `DT[, (names(DT)) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct, format="%Y%m%d%H%M")]`
R gives me an error, saying "'origin' must be supplied". In my data frame are more variables than the dates, I just didn't put them in here. Maybe this is a problem?

Comment: your data is not very clean or the way you read the data into R has converted the column into a numeric column. maybe read the columns in as `colClasses="character"`?